# Why is docker-compose ps different from docker ps?

Tags: docker

Why does docker compose create containers that are only accecible from docker-compose ps and that persist after killing running container ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't.

`docker ps` only shows running containers, `docker-compose ps` shows all containers related to the current compose file, running and stopped. `docker-compose kill` just force stops the container and it can be restarted with `docker-compose start`, it will therefore be visible when running `docker-compose ps` but not `docker ps`.

To list all containers with docker use `docker ps -a`. To removed stopped containers related to a compose file run `docker-compose rm`, if you want to stop and remove all containers, have a look at `docker-compose down`.

Answer (score -1):

docker-compose is the software wrapper around docker and there is not full support still. You can try to read a little bit about kubernets and mesos for the comparing different clusters built on top of docker or similar container systems.
[article on blog about swarm and compose](https://blog.docker.com/2015/02/orchestrating-docker-with-machine-swarm-and-compose/)