# Service added in second docker-compose file is orphaned and not visible in docker-compose ps output

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have the following docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3'
services:

    db:
        image: postgres:${PG_VERSION}
        ports:
            - "${DB_PORT}:5432"
        environment:
            - POSTGRES_USER=${SUPER_USER}
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${SUPER_PASS}
            - POSTGRES_DB=${DB_NAME}
            - SUPER_USER=${SUPER_USER}
            - SUPER_USER_PASSWORD=${SUPER_PASS}
            - DB_NAME=${DB_NAME}
            - DB_USER=${DB_USER}
            - DB_PASS=${DB_PASS}
            - DB_ANON_ROLE=${DB_ANON_ROLE}
        volumes:
            - ./initdb:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d

    # PostgREST
    postgrest:
        image: postgrest/postgrest
        ports:
            - "${API_PORT}:3000"
        links:
            - db:db
        environment:
            - PGRST_DB_URI=postgres://${DB_USER}:${DB_PASS}@${DB_HOST}:5432/${DB_NAME}
            - PGRST_DB_SCHEMA=${DB_SCHEMA}
            - PGRST_DB_ANON_ROLE=${DB_ANON_ROLE}
            - PGRST_JWT_SECRET=${JWT_SECRET}
        depends_on:
            - db

    swagger:
        image: swaggerapi/swagger-ui
        ports:
            - ${SWAGGER_PORT}:8080
        environment:
            API_URL: ${SWAGGER_API_URL-:http://localhost:${API_PORT}/
```

And another file docker-compose.prod.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
    db:
        volumes:
            - ./initdb/init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
            - ./var/postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
            - ./var/log/postgresql:/var/log/postgresql
            - ./etc/postgresql/postgresql.conf:/var/lib/postgresql/data/postgresql.conf

    nginx:
        image: nginx
        ports:
            - 80:80
            - 443:443
        volumes:
            - ./etc/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
            - ./var/log/nginx:/var/log/nginx
        depends_on:
            - postgrest
```

As you can see I am adding a few volumes to the db service, but importantly I have also added a new nginx service.

The reason I am adding it in this file is because nginx is not needed during development.

However, what is strange is when I issue the docker-compose up command as follows:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.prod.yml up -d
```

And then list the processes with

```
docker-compose ps
```

I get the following output

```
     Name                    Command               State               Ports             
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
api_db_1          docker-entrypoint.sh postgres    Up      0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp        
api_postgrest_1   /bin/sh -c exec postgrest  ...   Up      0.0.0.0:3000->3000/tcp        
api_swagger_1     /docker-entrypoint.sh sh / ...   Up      80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp
```

Notice that nginx is not here. However it is actually running, when I issue:

```
docker ps
```

I get the following output

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                   COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                      NAMES
ba281fd80743        nginx                   "/docker-entrypoint.…"   8 minutes ago       Up 8 minutes        0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp   api_nginx_1
d0028fdaecf5        postgrest/postgrest     "/bin/sh -c 'exec po…"   8 minutes ago       Up 8 minutes        0.0.0.0:3000->3000/tcp                     api_postgrest_1
1d6e3d689210        postgres:11.2           "docker-entrypoint.s…"   8 minutes ago       Up 8 minutes        0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp                     api_db_1
ed5fa7a71848        swaggerapi/swagger-ui   "/docker-entrypoint.…"   8 minutes ago       Up 8 minutes        80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp             api_swagger_1
```

So my question is, why is docker-compose not seeing nginx as part of the group of services?

NOTE: The reason I am using this override approach, and not using `extends`, is that `extends` does not support services with `links` and `depends_on` properties. My understanding is that combining files like this is the recommended approach. However I do understand why it is not possible to add new services in a secondary file.

For example see https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/#example-use-case, here the docs are adding a new `dbadmin` service using this method, but no mention that the service won't be included in the output of `docker-compose ps`, and that there will be warnings about orphans, for example:

```
$docker-compose down

Stopping api_postgrest_1 ... done
Stopping api_db_1        ... done
Stopping api_swagger_1   ... done
WARNING: Found orphan containers (api_nginx_1) for this project. If you removed or renamed this service in your compose file, you can run this command with the --remove-orphans flag to clean it up.
Removing api_postgrest_1 ... done
Removing api_db_1        ... done
Removing api_swagger_1   ... done
Removing network api_default
```

Tested on:

- Docker version 20.10.4, build d3cb89e
- Docker version 19.03.12-ce, build 48a66213fe

and:

- docker-compose version 1.27.0, build unknown
- docker-compose version 1.29.2, build 5becea4c

Comment: You can add an nginx definition to your base docker-compose with `profiles: ["none"]`, and then reset it to defual in the docker-compose.prod.yml - as you never use `docker-compose --profile xxx` this will make docker compose aware of nginx for normal deployment, and only deploy it when you deploy both files merged.

Answer (score 0):

So I literally figured it out as I was typing, and noticed a related question.

The trick is this https://stackoverflow.com/a/45515734/2685895

The reason why my new nginx service was not visible, is because `docker-compose ps` by default only looks at the `docker-compose.yml` file.

In order to get the expected output, one needs to specify both files,

In my case:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.prod.yml ps
```